# PHP MYSQL date range missed days

Tags: php, mysql, date

in DB,  there is also 26th and 31st days but not changing to OK.
only getting 3rd day and change to OK.

Where am i wrong in this code?

Code:

```
*$from   = date("Y-m-01"); 
$to     = date("Y-m-t"); // last day current month
$query  = "SELECT date FROM tbl_data WHERE date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' order by date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $date =  date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $row['date']);
}
$cursor =  date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $from);
$finish =  date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $to);
while ($cursor != $date)
    {
        echo date_format($cursor,'Y-m-d') . "--- Missed <br>";
        date_modify($cursor, '+1 day'); 

            while($cursor == $date)
                {
                    echo date_format($date,'Y-m-d') . "--- OK <br>";
                    date_modify($cursor, '+1 day'); 
                }
            while($cursor > $finish)
                {
                    die();
                }   
}*
```

Output:

2016-07-01--- Missed 
2016-07-02--- Missed 
2016-07-03--- OK 
2016-07-04--- Missed 
2016-07-05--- Missed 
2016-07-06--- Missed 
2016-07-07--- Missed 
2016-07-08--- Missed 
2016-07-09--- Missed 
2016-07-10--- Missed 
2016-07-11--- Missed 
2016-07-12--- Missed 
2016-07-13--- Missed 
2016-07-14--- Missed 
2016-07-15--- Missed 
2016-07-16--- Missed 
2016-07-17--- Missed 
2016-07-18--- Missed 
2016-07-19--- Missed 
2016-07-20--- Missed 
2016-07-21--- Missed 
2016-07-22--- Missed 
2016-07-23--- Missed 
2016-07-24--- Missed 
2016-07-25--- Missed 
2016-07-26--- Missed 
2016-07-27--- Missed 
2016-07-28--- Missed 
2016-07-29--- Missed 
2016-07-30--- Missed 
2016-07-31--- Missed

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to ask, please elaborate your question further.

Comment: Dont close your first while loop there, close it at the end

Comment: not changed i tried that

Comment: Isn't `$date` only being set to one date by being overwritten in the first loop?

Comment: all my code is based php and mysql it checks db and if in db there is date is filled this code changes to "OK" but if day is null it says "Missed"

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand but as far as I understand, you're trying to check whether there are record for iterated date or not.

The main point which you missed out is, you are only storing single date on `$date` variable. To clarify;

```
while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $date =  date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $row['date']);
}

/* at this point of code, your variable $date is exactly equal to 2016-07-03
* because you sorted all existing dates in descending order and last record is 2016-07-03
*/
```

After this code portion, your "OK" check is only valid for "2016-07-03". To correct the code, you should have array to store all days and use `in_array()` function to check existence.

Another alternative is applying these procedures inside while loop after changing ORDER BY direction. If two consecutive records are not consecutive days, you will fill these gap (second level) iteration.